# How to change `yuv420p(progressive)` to `yuv420p(tv, progressive)`?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a video `in.mp4`:

```
Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 375 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
```

I want to convert it into the following spec (need to change the time-base and also add an empty audio):

```
Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 20744 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn (default)
Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 131 kb/s (default)
```

Currently I'm using this `ffmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -i in.mp4 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v main -video_track_timescale 30k -c:a aac -map 0:a -map 1:v -shortest out.mp4
```

The output `out.mp4`

```
Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s (default)
Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 27 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn (default)
```

As you can see, the output audio stream matches what I wanted. But the output video stream is missing the "tv" part in the "yuv420p(tv, progressive)" spec.

**How do I add back the "tv" part in the "yuv420p(tv, progressive)" spec?**

My misc assumptions:

- In the output, the order of audio and video stream are changed. I assume that doesn't matter.
- In the input and the output, the bit-rate for both audio and video are change, but I assume it's okay because h264 and aac are not fixed bit-rate (I hope?).

Comment: See: https://jameshfisher.com/2021/01/13/mp4-can-encode-superwhite-and-superblack-thanks-to-analog-tv/
Looks like the magic is in : out_range=mpeg

Comment: We can mark the H.264 stream as "TV range" using bitstream filter: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i anullsrc -i in.mp4 -vf scale=out_range=tv -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v main -video_track_timescale 30k -c:a aac -map 0:a -map 1:v -shortest -bsf:v h264_metadata=video_full_range_flag=0 out.mp4`. The `scale=out_range=tv` filter is probably not required because "TV range" is the default.

Comment: Thanks you both for your suggestions. I will try both and report back when I get a chance (in a few hours).

Question to @Rotem to validate my understanding: I assume both our commands does a re-encoding of the video. If that's true, then, is the color range of that re-encoding the tv range, or the 0-255 range? Both ways, I cannot understand the apparent inconsistency between the actual output color range vs. the "tv" tag. I.e., if the actual output is tv range, then why the metadata don't contain the "tv" tag; if the actual output is 0-255 range, than why "out_range=tv" is default.

Comment: The actual output is tv range, because this the default for all codecs I know using YUV except JPEG. For historical reasons, the stream metadata that marks the range is not marked by default. I think that in AV1 codec it's mandatory. In H.264 it's a recommendation. It's also recommend to mark the color standard.

Comment: Adding `-bsf:v h264_metadata=video_full_range_flag=0` worked. Thanks to @Rotem. Just for the record, my working command: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -i in.mp4 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v main -bsf:v h264_metadata=video_full_range_flag=0 -video_track_timescale 30k -c:a aac -map 0:a -map 1:v -shortest out.mp4`